# CSS - Target background image in DIV

Tags: jquery, css

I'd like to target the `background-image` of a DIV so that I can apply a 'glow' style to it when the DIV is hovered over.

[see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/jT5b5/2/) for an exmaple of what my current setup is and how I'm attempting to do it now (albeit, targeting the div and not the image in the div).

Is this possible? If so, how :) ..if not, how might I change my HTML/CSS to give the same visual effect you see in the fiddle but allow the image to have the 'glow' apply to it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You want the arrow to glow, or the div?

Comment: You forgot to change that jsFiddle to use jQuery - it's set to the default of MooTools at the moment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A background image is binary data. You can't manipulate its contents using CSS.

The only way is to, on hover, switch the image to another file that has the glow around the arrow graphic:

```
.collapsible {
    background-image: url('/arrow_mini_up.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}

.collapsible:hover {
    background-image: url('/arrow_mini_up_glow.png');
}
```

Even if you use a data URI, it's the same thing: you need to specify one background image for the default state and another for the hover state:

```
.collapsible {
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,A0Giftt6...');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: right;
}

.collapsible:hover {
    background-image: url('data:image/png;base64,n4x71Al4...');
}
```

Comment: Ok, so is there a way in which I can put the image in it's own div maybe? and have it be positioned to the right as shown in the fiddle?

Comment: @codecraig: You can try placing a div inside your header div, then giving the inner div these styles: `position: absolute; right: 0;` and giving the header div `position: relative`. But why do you need to put it in its own div?

Comment: was looking to use CSS to add the glow instead of creating alternate images, that's all. Guess it doesn't have to be a separate div.

Comment: If the glow is to follow the outline of the arrow, CSS can't do it.

Comment: I voted this as the answer, although it's not what I was ultimately going for..it'll work. Thanks.